# Copy and paste file from sharepoint using pyhton and Office365-REST-Python-Client

Tags: python, office365api

I am using Office365-REST-Python-Client and I want to copy and paste a file on sharepoint.
I am following the example from [here](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/copy_using_path.py) but I am still getting error.

the code:

```
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_url, context_auth)

file_from = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_path("Shared Documents/Subfolder/my_file.xlsx")
folder_to = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_path("Shared Documents/Subfolder")
file_to = file_from.copyto_using_path(folder_to, True).execute_query()
print("{0} copied into {1}".format(file_from, file_to))
```

Error: ClientRequestException: (None, None, "401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: [https://mysite.sharepoint.com/\_api/Web/getFileByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl='Shared%20Documents%2FSubfolder%2Fmy_file.xlsx')/CopyToUsingPath(DecodedUrl=%3Coffice365.sharepoint.folders.folder.Folder%20object%20at%200x7f45e7f0f310%3E,bOverWrite=true)"](https://mysite.sharepoint.com/%5C_api/Web/getFileByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl=%27Shared%20Documents%2FSubfolder%2Fmy_file.xlsx%27)/CopyToUsingPath(DecodedUrl=%3Coffice365.sharepoint.folders.folder.Folder%20object%20at%200x7f45e7f0f310%3E,bOverWrite=true)%22))

I have access and permissions to the file/folder cause I created the file in the step before.